# React Apollo with react-hooks useEffect warning in console

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

The following console warning has been dogging me for days...

```
Warning: The final argument passed to useEffect changed size between renders. The order and size of this array must remain constant.        react-dom.development.js:530

Previous: [true, 1, , ]
Incoming: [false, 7, , [object Object], function () { return queryData.afterExecute({ lazy: lazy }); }, 0]
    in SampleQuery (created by App)
    in ApolloProvider (created by App)
    in App

Warning: The final argument passed to useEffect changed size between renders. The order and size of this array must remain constant.        react-dom.development.js:530

Previous: []
Incoming: [function () {
        return function () { return queryData.cleanup(); };
    }]
    in SampleQuery (created by App)
    in ApolloProvider (created by App)
    in App
```

The code for the app is as follows...

**app.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';

import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import {ApolloProvider} from '@apollo/react-hooks';

import SampleQuery from "./sample-query";

interface AppProps {
    compiler: string;
    framework: string;
}

const App = (props: AppProps) => {

    const cache = new InMemoryCache();
    const link = new HttpLink({
        uri: 'http://localhost:4000/',
    });


    const client = new ApolloClient({
        // Provide required constructor fields
        cache: cache,
        link: link,

        // Provide some optional constructor fields
        name: 'react-web-client',
        version: '1.3',
        queryDeduplication: false,
        defaultOptions: {
            watchQuery: {
                fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
            },
        }
    });

    return (
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
            <h1>Hello from {props.compiler} and {props.framework}!</h1>
            <SampleQuery />
        </ApolloProvider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

**sample-query.tsx...**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

interface Link {
    id: string;
    description: string;
}

const SAMPLE_QUERY = gql`{
    feed {
        links {
            id
            description
        }
    }
}`;

const SampleQuery = () => {

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(SAMPLE_QUERY);

    if (loading) return <p>Loading ...</p>;

    const links = (data && data.feed.links) || [];

    return (<ul>
          {links.map((link:Link, idx:number) => {
              return (
                <li key={idx}>
                    <span>{link.id}</span>
                    <span> : </span>
                    <span>{link.description}</span>
                </li>
              );
          })}
      </ul>)
};

export default SampleQuery;
```

I'm unsure why I get the warning as I'm pretty close to the examples from the React Apollo docs. Hopefully someone here has experienced this before and could point me in the right direction.

Comment: For full context the repo can be accsessed here...
https://github.com/darrownet/grats-boilerplate

Comment: This is most likely due to the fact that your `query` prop in the `SampleQuery` component changes, but you're not really handling this action properly. You need to use a `useEffect` that will "manually" do the "refetch" step when your `prop` changes.

Comment: @goto1 Thanks for the reply. I've moved the GraphQL query to the SampleQuery component (repo has been updated). Unfortunately it did not remove the warning. I'm wondering if my custom build might have something to do with it?

Comment: Yeah it's strange. I just tried replicating this on a clean app bootstrapped with `create-react-app` and no issues here. Must be something with your setup.

Comment: Fixed it. Turns out he problem was in webpack.dev.js. Totally removing the redundant hot reloading entry point was what needed to happen